# Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32,

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

Can any one tell me whats wrong in this query

```
var result = from m in _ftsDataContext.SubCategories 
             join n in _ftsDataContext.Categories
             on m.CategoryID equals n.CategoryID
             select new {
                 SubCategoryID = m.SubCategoryID,
                 Name = n.CategoryName + ' ' + m.SubCategoryName
             };
```

i m getting this error : Unable to create a constant value of type `System.Object`. Only primitive types (such as `Int32`, `String`, and `Guid`) are supported in this context

Comment: It looks like [this error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#RefNonScalarClosures), but I don't see anything that would cause it in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with " " :

```
Name = n.CategoryName + " " + m.SubCategoryName
```